# Nested Dictionary using enum as key

Tags: typescript

I have two enums imported from a different files

```js
export enum Id {
    X = 'AA',
    Y = 'BB',
    Z = 'CC'
}
```

```
export enum Place {
    us = 'USA',
    ind = 'INDIA',
}
```

I want to create a dictionary something like:

```py
const valueThreshold = {
    Id.X : {
        Place.us : {
            'foo' : 1,
            }
        Place.ind : {
            'foo' : 1,
            }
     },
    Id.Y : {
        Place.us : {
            'foo' : 6,
            }
        Place.ind : {
            'foo' : 4,
            }
     }
}
```

which I can then query like
`valueThreshold[Id.X][Place.us]['foo']`.

Note my query would be something like `valueThreshold['AA']['USA']['foo']` when executed.

I tried creating using `Record`(see below) however I can't seem to use the enum value as key. I get an error  `error    Extra space after computed key 'Id.X'` which means the key was taken as 'Id.X'. I want the key to be 'AA'

```js
import  { Id, Place } from './config';


const valueThreshold: Record<string, Record<string, Record<string, number>>> = {
    [Id.x] : {
        [Place.us] : {
            'foo' : 5
        },
        [Place.ind] : {
            'foo' : 1
        }
    }
}
```

Any pointers on how to do this correctly would be really really helpful.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @axiac Updated with code snippet of using Record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) is the correct way. You should delete the space after the computed key:

```
enum Id {
    X = 'AA',
    Y = 'BB',
    Z = 'CC'
}
enum Place {
    us = 'USA',
    ind = 'INDIA',
}

const valueThreshold = {
    [Id.X]: {
        [Place.us]: {
            'foo': 1,
        },
        [Place.ind]: {
            'foo': 1,
        }
    },
    [Id.Y]: {
        [Place.us]: {
            'foo': 6,
        },
        [Place.ind]: {
            'foo': 4,
        }
    }
}

console.log(valueThreshold[Id.X][Place.us]['foo'])

// Use enum as the key of a Record 
const valueThreshold2: Record<Id, Record<Place, Record<string, number>>> = {
    [Id.X]: {
        [Place.us]: {
            'foo': 5
        },
        [Place.ind]: {
            'foo': 1
        }
    },
    [Id.Y]: {
        [Place.us]: {
            'foo': 6,
        },
        [Place.ind]: {
            'foo': 4,
        }
    },
    [Id.Z]: {
        [Place.us]: {
            'foo': 2,
        },
        [Place.ind]: {
            'foo': 3,
        }
    }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAkgJlA3gKCmqANKBeKByAQQLwBpV0BNHfAIRtPLQC1q8BhNvZAX2VEigAFADYBDAMbAkjKGADOrAKoBlYmXRQAliAS48MAHIARGGp7Jk4gPYg5AFygA3UcLDAAKgAsATsDmerYV1pDQBteAA6DABdAC4QjXRQkQlgCPk4hMTEvAAzKys8eIBGdWyobjLs5LFJCO04TJRynPzCkqrE3g1KmXC4CIommTCUuoz45pb0PIKiqAA2Tp7lpLG0huHpmbb5gBZVtG70Xl5LGzlAtOErAHMACmdXDx8-AKD+qOia1PS5b9mhWiAEoLAB6MFQRRyKT8aCiBR2TxSADWwAAnlArLkoKIoAAlYDWbwIc62BxPNxeXz+QJwABM8UJxLgAB54CQCUSrCTWetOcyeWz7N5tLdOeAIAAjYDeAB8CuoUzQnxikxGa1qaQmWWmgPmAFYNUdDlAfnVNurtmh9SVjRUZL0wpEhlbyubtf83dtbYtTU73et6jottbfQd7ccTX1IkxQ9UgzrlXrdvF6f7TR7g41vSm5vEAMz+x08IA)

Comment: That works!! Thanks a lot. Was stuck with this on my first PR on new job. I should probably try a different occupation ‍